# How to format key with angular?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to format keynote from spotify API

[image: us]

How can I format this number to a standard pitch class notation?

```
 <div class="key-note">{{trackFeature.key}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `key` will be a fixed value of `0 <= key < 12`, the quickest way would be to define the list of symbols(?) as an array (possibly in an external file eg. **config.ts**).

config.ts

```js
export const NOTATIONS = [ 
  'C', 
  'C♯/D♭', 
  'D', 
  'D♯/E♭', 
  'E', 
  'F', 
  'F♯/G♭', 
  'G', 
  'G♯/A♭', 
  'A', 
  'A♯/B♭', 
  'B' 
];
```

Source: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_equal_temperament)

And use it in the component

Controller

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NOTATIONS } from './config';

export class AppComponent  {
  notations = NOTATIONS;
  ...
}
```

Template

```html
<div class="key-note">{{ notations[trackFeature.key] || 'Key unavailable' }}</div>
```

Comment: where should I add the notations array?

Comment: @nathannewyen: It depends on your requirement. You could define it directly in a component if you wish. I've defined it in a separate file so it can be reused. I've updated the answer.